# Remove 2 last directories from a path with sed

Tags: bash, sed

How could I remove last 2 directories from my path?

Path example:

`./dir1/dir2/file-example.json`

How I want it to be:

`./dir1/`

Comment: Do you have these in a shell variable, in a text file, or elsewhere?

Comment: they are stored in a shell file

Comment: You can use regex, like this: `echo "./dir1/dir2/file-example.json" | sed -re 's|(./\w*[^/]).*|\1|g'`

Answer (score 1):

If that path is in variable, I would suggest using dedicate tools for that.

For instance, in `zsh`:

```
file=./dir1/dir2///file-example.json
parent=$file:h:h
```

(head of head).

Or with `bash` and GNU utilities:

```
IFS= read -rd '' parent < <(
  dirname -z -- "$file" | xargs -r0 dirname -z --)
```

Doing it with `sed` means you have to implement the algorithm by hand, and if you want to handle all cases as nicely as `dirname` or `zsh`'s `:h` do, that can be complicated. Things to consider:

- trailing `/`'s should be ignored (but not all of them in the case where the input file is `/` or `///`)
- Other sequences of two or more `/`s should be considered the same as a single `/` except possibly for the case of `//foo/bar` where that `//` may need to be treated specially on some systems (explains why I added `///` to the example above to demonstrate things).
- the dirname of `foo` should be `.`
- the dirname of `/` should be `/`
- remember that file paths can contain any sequence of non NUL bytes. That includes sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters or that represent the newline character. The path may be longer than LINE_MAX (and some `sed` implementations will not handle lines longer than that).

Doing it with the GNU implementation of `sed` should be possible as long as you use `-z` and it's called in the `C`/`POSIX` locale, but it would not be trivial.

If it's to find the parent directory of the parent directory of the `file-example.json` files, you can just do:

```
parents=(*/**/file-example.json(ND:h:h))
```

in zsh. Or with `bash` 4.4+ and GNU utilities:

```
readarray -td '' parents < <(
  find . -mindepth 2 -name file-example.json -print0 |
    LC_ALL=C gawk -F/ -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '
      {NF -= 2; print}'
)
```

To get those directories in the `$parents` array.

Comment: I think my explanation was not really good, but this is what I would like, is it possible?


My code:


```#!/bin/bash


for filename in `find . -name "file-example.json" -print`
do
    echo $filename >> test.sh

done```

echo does this:
```./dir1/dir2/file-example.json```

I want this to loop through all my folders that have "file-example.json" and then removes /dir2/file-example.json from path.

Comment: @EeroJürgenson please add that to your question so that it's easy for everyone to see. (You can format it with `{}` too.)